# Parse query in Phonegap returning error 100 XMLHTTPRequest failed

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, parse-platform

I am new to Phonegap. I am developing an app with Parse integration. I am also using AngularJS for data binding. My code is:

```
Parse.initialize(APP_KEY, JS_KEY);

$scope.allServices = [];

var Services = Parse.Object.extend("Service");
        var query = new Parse.Query(Services);
        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
                    var object = results[i];
                    $scope.allServices.push(new getService(object));
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
```

But getting ERROR in alert like:

[image]

How can I get result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was including parse.js after jquery in HTML. I changed the sequence and it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/parse-1.3.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After setting this sequence, it is giving result.